# No installed app with label 'polls' - activating models - error

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-apps

I am learning Django3.2.5, from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial02/. I created a project with the name, 'mysite', then 'polls' app, and using the default 'SQLite' database.

Project's (mysite) file hierarchy:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        asgi.py
        wsgi.py
```

App's (polls) file hierarchy:

```
polls/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    apps.py
    migrations/
        __init__.py
    models.py
    tests.py
    views.py
```

mysite/mysite/settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.29.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '4)2m9i5*y=icl-9bpiw#w@n!(y^y%38+8smh70mqupeppb&o#r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

mysite/polls/models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

mysite/polls/apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PollsConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'polls'
```

When I run, `python3 manage.py makemigrations polls`, it throws out this error `No installed app with label 'polls'.`

I am new to Django, please help.

Comment: Is `polls` inside `mysite` (where `manage.py` is)?

Comment: If not, try to move it there. In the tutorial, there is this line: `To create your app, make sure you’re in the same directory as manage.py and type this command:`

Comment: Yes, it is, in the outer mysite directory, where manage.py is. Yet, it shows the same error. @bdbd

Comment: Have you tried to follow the steps again from an empty project?

Answer (score 0):

In Installed apps
you have written this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

]

'polls.apps.PollsConfig', it is wrong syntax
instead of this write

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'polls.apps.PollsAppConfig',
...
]
```

Comment: Hi Chinmay, can you please explain this to me? I tried this, it did not work out, and threw the same error. Aren't django.* apps are all default to running django?

Comment: Hi,  for django to know that an app has been created we need to write app name in installed apps
your app name is polls so you can also try this like write  'polls' after 'django.contrib.staticfiles', in installed apps

Comment: Are we not doing the same by adding, 'polls.apps.PollsConfig', in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: yes we are doing the same thing and what we are doing is correct and i think now there might be another issue. if any migrations file has been made try to delete that and rerun makemigrations command. it might solve it.
did you try to add 'polls' after 'django.contrib.staticfiles', in installed apps

Comment: I have the same problem. I am able to migrate all the other apps but not the newly added.

Answer (score 0):

Try **python manage.py makemigrations**
Without using 'polls'

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).